# Pairs of actors with the most movies as couple

Tags: acting, romance

I'm looking for the pair of actors playing as a couple or romantically involved in the most unrelated movies.

For example, Emma Stone and Ryan Gosling were romantically engaged in 3 separate movies: *Crazy, Stupid, Love*, then *Gangster Squad* and finally *La La Land*.

I'm looking for unrelated movies: Julie Walters and Mark Williams (Ms. and M. Weasley in *Harry Potter*) count for one, even though it was eight movies.

And I'm looking for couple or romance (even though the line might be hard to tell between romance and friendship in some movies). For example, Jennifer Lawrence and Bradley Cooper have a count of three (*Silver Lining Playbook*, *Serena* and *American Hustle*), as they were not romantically engaged in *Joy*.

Answer (score 4):

[Fred Astaire and Ginger Rogers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Astaire_and_Ginger_Rogers) shared 10 films between them, being a couple in each one (you couldn't really have a male/female lead in those days without them being romantically involved)

1933 - [Flying down to Rio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Down_to_Rio).

1934 - [The Gay Divorcee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gay_Divorcee)

1935 - [Roberta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roberta_(1935_film))

1935 - [Top Hat](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0027125/)

1936 - [Follow the Fleet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow_the_Fleet)

1936 - [Swing Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_Time_(film))

1937 - [Shall we Dance?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shall_We_Dance_(1937_film))

1938 - [Carefree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carefree_(film))

1939 - [The Story of Vernon and Irene Castle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_Vernon_and_Irene_Castle)

1949 - [The Barkleys of Broadway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Barkleys_of_Broadway)

There might be other couples with more films, but Fred and Ginger seemed the obvious and iconic pairing.